# Create an xarray dataset form a series of GeoTIFFs and clipping problem

Tags: python, raster, rioxarray, xarray

I am trying to create a dataset from a series of GeoTIFFs (one .tiff file per day) and then clip it with a given geometry (shapefile).

The TIFF files, one per day, have this format: e.g. day 29-07-2022 is "'20200729_LAI_10_li.tif'".
So, to create a DataArray first, I do:

```
rasterfiles = '*_LAI_*.tif'
file_names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(rasterfiles)]
```

Then:

```
d = pd.to_datetime([f[0:8] for f in file_names], format='%Y%m%d')

# Create variable used for time axis
time_var = xr.Variable('time', d)

# Load in and concatenate all individual GeoTIFFs
geotiffs_da = xr.concat([rioxarray.open_rasterio(i) for i in geotiff_list], dim=time_var)

print(geotiffs_da)

<xarray.DataArray (time: 3, band: 1, y: 1917, x: 2712)>
array([[[[0.841899  , 0.49796602, 0.49547264, ..., 0.48724672,
          0.48883843, 0.4640673 ],
         [0.85895765, 0.48707363, 0.48711962, ..., 0.45904365,
          0.459719  , 0.42584667],
         [0.78813803, 0.53859097, 0.5262373 , ..., 0.4329257 ,
          0.4358901 , 0.40675077],
         ...,
         [0.6452744 , 0.65063107, 0.65305126, ..., 0.5969078 ,
          0.62472266, 0.4752977 ],
         [0.6464008 , 0.63994086, 0.6416756 , ..., 0.4579691 ,
          0.46382567, 0.38283092],
         [0.6430859 , 0.6402164 , 0.6443309 , ..., 0.31999364,
          0.32463393, 0.47300756]]],


       [[[0.8459085 , 0.50151324, 0.5023752 , ..., 0.52387303,
          0.52565217, 0.49500299],
         [0.8692708 , 0.49452382, 0.4949082 , ..., 0.4948238 ,
          0.49642542, 0.45970017],
         [0.7755667 , 0.54607254, 0.53799886, ..., 0.466479  ,
...
          0.57320845, 0.4891631 ],
         [0.63085663, 0.6266309 , 0.627114  , ..., 0.4272701 ,
          0.4306107 , 0.39424646],
         [0.63262284, 0.6350342 , 0.6357571 , ..., 0.333524  ,
          0.33858237, 0.4980796 ]]],


       [[[0.84991807, 0.50506043, 0.50927776, ..., 0.5604993 ,
          0.56246597, 0.52593863],
         [0.87958395, 0.50197405, 0.5026968 , ..., 0.530604  ,
          0.53313184, 0.49355364],
         [0.7629953 , 0.5535541 , 0.5497604 , ..., 0.5000323 ,
          0.5010995 , 0.45842043],
         ...,
         [0.6191411 , 0.6167446 , 0.62055385, ..., 0.50110066,
          0.5216943 , 0.5030285 ],
         [0.6153125 , 0.61332095, 0.6125524 , ..., 0.39657116,
          0.3973957 , 0.40566203],
         [0.62215984, 0.62985206, 0.62718326, ..., 0.34705433,
          0.3525308 , 0.52315164]]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int32 1
  * x            (x) float64 4.088e+05 4.088e+05 ... 4.359e+05 4.359e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 ... 4.531e+06 4.531e+06
    spatial_ref  int32 0
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-07-29 2020-07-30 2020-07-31
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:       Area
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:  7.292471408844
    STATISTICS_MEAN:     0.99665955765665
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:  0.050000000745058
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:   1.1692453497126
    _FillValue:          -3.4e+38
    scale_factor:        1.0
    add_offset:          0.0
```

After this, I put all together in a dataset:

```
# Covert our xarray.DataArray into a xarray.Dataset
geotiffs_ds = geotiffs_da.to_dataset("band")
geotiffs_ds = geotiffs_ds.rename({1: 'LAI'})
print(geotiffs_ds)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 3, y: 1917, x: 2712)
Coordinates:
  * x            (x) float64 4.088e+05 4.088e+05 ... 4.359e+05 4.359e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 ... 4.531e+06 4.531e+06
    spatial_ref  int32 0
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-07-29 2020-07-30 2020-07-31
Data variables:
    LAI          (time, y, x) float32 0.8419 0.498 0.4955 ... 0.3525 0.5232
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:       Area
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:  7.292471408844
    STATISTICS_MEAN:     0.99665955765665
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:  0.050000000745058
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:   1.1692453497126
    _FillValue:          -3.4e+38
    scale_factor:        1.0
    add_offset:          0.0
```

Now, I need to clip this dataset, extracting the LAI values within a geometry (polygon shapefile). What I do is:

```
area_shp = gpd.read_file('./test_area.shp') # read shp file from sampling area
clipped = geotiffs_ds.rio.clip(area_shp.geometry.apply(mapping), area_shp.crs, drop=False)
```

But when I try to plot the values, I see strange behaviour:

```
    gv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')
    dataset = gv.Dataset(geotiffs_ds.isel(time=0)
    ensemble = dataset.to(gv.Image, ['x', 'y'])

gv.output(ensemble.opts(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True, fig_size=200, backend='matplotlib'),
          backend='matplotlib')
```

[image: dataset plot]

I think the problem is that the LAI variable (Data Variable in Dataset, see above) should not be here, or there is something else I am doing wrong or missing.

By the way, when I try to do the same with a DataArray instead of a DataSet, the clipped DataArray returns me negative values and I don't know why:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 3, y: 533, x: 222)>
array([[[-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        ...,
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38]],

       [[-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
...
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38]],

       [[-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        ...,
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38],
        [-3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38, ..., -3.4e+38, -3.4e+38,
         -3.4e+38]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    band         int32 1
  * x            (x) float64 4.088e+05 4.088e+05 ... 4.359e+05 4.359e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 4.55e+06 ... 4.531e+06 4.531e+06
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-07-29 2020-07-30 2020-07-31
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:       Area
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:  7.292471408844
    STATISTICS_MEAN:     0.99665955765665
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:  0.050000000745058
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:   1.1692453497126
    scale_factor:        1.0
    add_offset:          0.0
    _FillValue:          -3.4e+38
```